# Segmentation fault while reversing every K elements of a linkedlist

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse the linked list in C++. Specific problem statement is this:
Given a singly linked list and an integer `K`, reverses the nodes of the list `K` at a time and returns modified linked list.

Example: Given linked list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 and `K=2`,

Modified linked list should be:  2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 6 -> 5.

But my code runs into segmentation fault. And I tried everything but not able to figure out whats wrong. Please help. TIA.

My code:

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

ListNode* reverseSubList(ListNode* prev, ListNode* start, int sz){

    ListNode *current, *next;
    current = start;
    while (sz>0) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        sz--;
    }

    return prev;  
}

ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* A, int B) {

    ListNode *start, *end;
    int i;
    start = A;
    end = NULL;
    while (start!=NULL) {
        end = reverseSubList(end, start, B); //end stores the first element of the last k elements reversed.
        start = end->next; 
    }

    return end;   
}

int main() {
    ListNode *linkedlist = new ListNode(10);
    ListNode *temp, *next;
    temp = linkedlist;
    int i=9;
    while (i>0) {
        next = new ListNode(i*2);
        temp->next = next;
        temp = temp->next;
        i--;
    }

    for (temp=linkedlist; temp->next!= NULL; temp = temp->next)
        cout<<temp->val<<" ";

    next = reverseList(linkedlist, 3);
    cout<<"\n";

    for (temp=next; temp->next!= NULL; temp = temp->next)
        cout<<temp->val<<" ";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : I agree with the first part of your comment, but to be fair, I believe the OP *has* included an MCVE.

Comment: @Martin That's a stock comment I'm frequently using. I'm not going to adapt it all the time I apply it.

Comment: I would relook at your code, it appears that you have no error checking in your `reverseSubList` function either, so if you have a list of size 10, and your passing in a 3 for K, this means this sublist will run atleast 4 times(so its going to move 12 elements), at which pointer current ends up being null, and your defereferencing null...  maybe change `while(sz > 0)` to `while(sz > 0 && current != NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My debugger told me that `current` is NULL at some point (see below), and dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is UB (and usually ends up in a segfault).

```
ListNode* reverseSubList(ListNode* prev, ListNode* start, int sz) {

  ListNode *current, *next;
  current = start;
  while (sz>0) {
    next = current->next;   // <<< current can be NULL here
  ....
```

To debug modify like this:

```
ListNode* reverseSubList(ListNode* prev, ListNode* start, int sz) {

  ListNode *current, *next;
  current = start;
  while (sz>0) {
    if (current == NULL)
    {
       printf("Fixme");
       exit(1);
    }
    next = current->next;   // <<< current can be NULL here
  ....
```

or better: learn how to use your debugger and use it. It will quickly pay off.